# Как сейчас обстоят дела с фрагментацией кучи?

Tags: java, c++, linux, c, windows

Давным-давно была система DOS и у нее была проблема - для многих приложений типа серверов баз данных при долгой работе куча сильно фрагментировалась. И хотя свободное место в куче было, некоторые запросы не могли быть выполнены, так как не было непрерывного свободного участка кучи.

Время шло и сейчас у нас есть и много памяти в ОЗУ и есть своп-файл. Но тем не менее и объемы данных выросли.

Вопросы:

1. Как сейчас обстоят дела с фрагментацией кучи? Есть ли проблема фрагментации кучи для приложений, которые должны работать с аптаймом в годы и десятилетия типа поисковых машин гугла или баз данных центробанков во всем мире?
2. Есть ли реализации куч со сжатием? Применяются ли они в реальных приложениях?

UPD1:

Еще вопросы:

3. Как обстоят дела с фрагментацией кучи в языках со сбором мусора типа Явы? Если Ява-приложение работает долго, то вполне возможен такой вариант, что свободное место в куче есть, но нет непрерывного свободного места для размещения очередной переменной. Есть ли сжатие кучи в Ява и других языках со сборкой мусора?
4. Да собственно и системная куча в операционных системах тоже подвержена фрагментации. Там постоянно создаются/уничтожаются системные объекты типа семафоров и буферов межпроцессорного обмена. Системная куча тоже может фрагментироваться до потери работоспособности. Выполняется ли сжатие системной кучи в современных ОС?

UPD2:

> Я правильно понимаю, что под сжатием/дефрагментацией кучи вы понимаете
>   не просто слияние 2-х смежных участков, ставших свободными (это всегда
>   и всюду было)? – avp 3 часа назад

Естественно, не только это. Нужно в куче иметь информацию о всех выданных указателях и при сжатии кучи корректировать эти указатели в программе. Конечно, при такой схеме указатель будет классом, а не просто машинным адресом. Может быть понадобится счетчик экземпляров указателя. Может быть понадобится организовать эти указатели в список и при сжатии кучи все их корректировать, двигаясь по списку.

UPD3:

> Нет, просто интересно что вы думаете про ресурсы, которые понадобятся
>   для корректировки всех указателей (ссылок) на данные в перемещаемых
>   фрагментах – avp 7 секунд назад

Дополнительные ресурсы понадобятся, это несомненно. Но это лучше, чем аварийное завершение приложения или отказ в обслуживании по причине фрагментированной кучи. Другое дело, не очень понятно, насколько это актуально. Для сеансных приложений типа утром запустил Word, написал документ, закрыл Word, это может быть и не очень актуально. А для серверов, которые должны работать годами не выключаясь и внутри которых постоянно идет нарезка памяти это может быть актуально. Но пока что никто не поделился информацией, насколько это актуально. Хотя, конечно, большие фирмы должны проводить такие исследования, насколько часто у них встает проблема фрагментированности кучи.

UPD4:

> @pepsicoca1, "для серверов, которые должны работать годами не
>   выключаясь" -- обычно при построении надежных систем в них
>   предусматривается вероятность отказа любого компонента и
>   соответственно процедуру переключения на резервную конфигурацию.
>   Например, в HA серверах это обычно называют переключением пакета. Если
>   монитор обнаруживает неисправность, он выполняет эту процедуру. Если
>   требуются регламентные работы (скажем, по железу), то ее выполняет
>   админ. Если пакет (прикладной софт) сам диагностирует неполадки, то он
>   шлет сообщение монитору. И т.д. и т.п. – avp 13 часов назад

Аппаратное резервирование на уровне RAID массивов позволяет по-горячему менять дисковые накопители. Да и меняют их не по факту сбоя, а по достижению выработки ХХХ часов, гарантированных производителем.

Если же действительно стоит две разные физически базы данных, работающих параллельно, то один сервер должен работать, а второй должен аппаратно(!) зеркалится. Если первый сервер сбойнул (по любой причине, включая фрагментацию кучи), то второй должен стартануть и в реальном времени(!) перехватить обслуживание на себя.

UPD5:

> @avp, Я понимаю так, как нужно. Не все данные хранятся сжатыми,
>   система сжимает только ту информацию, которую считает необходимой.
>   Дальше обсуждать нет желания. – AR Hovsepyan 14 часов назад

Кстати, это свежая идея. Куча с архивацией/деархивацией в реальном времени, по типу сжатого тома в дисковой подсистеме. Для однотипных данных может дать реальную экономию памяти. :-)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87686/discussion-on-question-by-pepsicoca1-------).