# Что такое фрагментация кучи?

Tags: память, ос

Пожалуйста поделитесь опытом по теме. 
Что это? Как ее выявить? Как с ней бороться? Может есть что-то важное на что нужно обратить внимание?

Comment: а она вам мешает? обычно такие проблемы на микроконтроллерах с ограниченной памятью, а на больших машинах paging выбрасывает долго не использующиеся страницы из ОЗУ

Comment: @PavelGridin Нет не мешает, вопрос задан для просвещения.

Answer (score 1):

Некоторое время назад я задавал похожий вопрос. Местные доброхоты закрыли его, но в обсуждении (перемещенном в чат другими доброхотами) осталось несколько интересных ссылок на ПО, которое обеспечивает (якобы) дефрагментацию кучи в рантайме. Вот ссылка на обсуждение:

[Как сейчас обстоят дела с фрагментацией кучи? [закрыт]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927066/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8)

Ну а так по жизни - 99% приложений имеют сеансный характер и куча просто не успевает фрагментироваться. Остальные 1% приложений, которые должны работать с большим аптаймом, видно не используют кучу. Либо у них создаются-уничтожаются объекты сравнимого и более-менее постоянного (и маленького) размера, и тогда фрагментирования кучи не происходит.

Но есть еще вопрос о фрагментации системной кучи, то есть об объектах ОС, которые динамически создаются и уничтожаются в процессе работы. Этот вопрос тоже не очень ясен, как с этим борются (и побеждают) разработчики ОС.

UPD1:

Вот еще похожий вопрос:

[Можно ли писать на С++ со сборщиком мусора?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/874159/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%A1-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)